# Dataset: what to put for blank date fields?

Tags: python, database, pandas

I am creating a dataset by pulling information from Trello (task organizer). One column will have a date a card was moved to a list, if that event occurred. There are a few cards that were never moved to that list, so I will have some rows with no date.

What's the correct value to put in these rows that are without a date? What is the best approach from a data management perspective so that blank fields won't affect formulas and plotting the data?

I am working with Pandas for data analysis.

For example, the pseudo code would run like this:

```
for card in list_of_cards:
    if card.location == 'DONE_LIST':
        return card.date_moved
    else:
        return None  # <--- or should it be '', 'NaN', '0', ' ', or something else?
```

Comment: `pandas` has a whole [section of their docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html) discussing this topic

Comment: `np.where(np.array(list_of_cards) == 'DONE_LIST', card.date_moved, np.nan)` And to address your question, that depends on what the data is and the context. Don't expect a serious answer without providing more details.